# Get random numbers in the 3x3 table or larger

Tags: excel

Please ads & support readers

I have a 3x3 table numbered from 1-9 as shown in the attachment.

Now how do I get the random number in this table shown in column E1?

And a little more upgrading (for myself) that is for example: E1 random cell B2 - ie 6 (according to his picture) - is always poured the same ink B2.

[image]

Comment: "is always poured the same ink B" - What ??

Comment: `Int ((9 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)` Random number between 1 - 9

Answer (score 1):

To actually get a random value from your table, which presumably might not always have the numbers 1 to 9 you can use this formula in E1

`=INDEX($A$1:$C$3,RANDBETWEEN(1,3),RANDBETWEEN(1,3))`

For differently sized tables you can use this generic formula

`=INDEX(Table,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(Table)),RANDBETWEEN(1,COLUMNS(Table)))`

You can use conditional formatting to highlight which number was picked

Select the range `A1:C3` and apply conditional formatting with this formula

`=A1=$E$1`

format as required

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to act as random number generator, and print result on cell E1.

```
Sub random_num()

'Initialize the random number generator
Randomize

Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("x")

'Random whole number between 1 and 9 :
random_number = Int(9 * Rnd) + 1

wk.Cells(1, "E").Value = random_number

End Sub
```